# Show number of items in Folder in ListView

Tags: 2007, folder, javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a solution that displays the number of items that are stored in a folder of a list.
Maybe this can be done with javascript/jquery, but I actually don't want to reinvent the wheel.
If anyone has seen such a solution, I would very much appreciate any hints :)
Thanks in advance
Tobi

Answer (score 1):

First check out this link to learn how to turn on metadata for Folders:

> http://sharepoint-guru.blogspot.com/2007/06/adding-metadata-to-folder.html

Second check out this link for adding the ItemChildCount to your folder:

> http://weblogs.asp.net/sharadkumar/archive/2008/06/27/showing-child-items-in-hierarchical-sharepoint-lists-with-multiple-content-types.aspx

For a Javascript variation check out this cool link on how to write HTML in a calculated column (which includes some Javascript.) It's not the full answer but I think you will get what you want out of the first two links:

> h____ttp://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/

Comment: Did this answer the question for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out setting the Totals property in the View settings? I believe you can set the Totals to count the number os Title in the list. This sould be applicable on folders as well...

Comment: yes this gives me a count on the current items in the list.
But it does not fit my requirements.
Imagine a list with items and folders in it.
And next to every folder icon there should be the number of items inside the folder.
-foldername (3)
-foldername2 (5)
-item
...
this won't work with the described count property :(
thanks anyway for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to sharepoint 2010 :-P. Maybe this could help you out:

http://weblogs.asp.net/sharadkumar/archive/2008/06/27/showing-child-items-in-hierarchical-sharepoint-lists-with-multiple-content-types.aspx